# Swift / C Struct array memory

Tags: c, arrays, swift

Currently working on a Swift wrapper for a C-library, and facing a challenge for which I can't seem to find a solve.

The C library I'm porting has a C struct instance, which functions as an engine (i.e. it has to be initialized, before being able to do anything).

The format of the engine struct:

```
struct engine {
  int8_t init;
  int8_t started;
  int8_t stopped;

  struct engineHandlers engine_handlers[MAX_ENGINE_HANDLERS]; 
};
```

In order to be able to initialize and correctly access the memory of the struct, I've created following mirror of above in Swift:

```
public struct swiftEngine {
  var initialized: CChar = 0
  var started: CChar = 0
  var stopped: CChar = 0
  var engineHandlers: [engineHandlers] = [engineHandlers()]
}
```

I then make sure to allocate the correct amount of memory:

```
let runEngine = UnsafeMutablePointer<swiftEngine>.alloc( Int( sizeof( swiftEngine ) ) )
```

And then pass `runEngine` to the initialize function in the C library.

If I try to access the engine's memory right after initializing it w. `print(runEngine.memory)` it prints everything as expected (i.e. all values and engineHandlers in array).

But as soon as I move on to a new function and try to access the same engine (passing exact same instance & address) Xcode throws an `LLDB` error (`()-> Int32`) as soon as it tries to print out engineHandlers whereas other values have been kept. I have tested with other arrays such as `[CInt] = 5`, and that results in same behavior. Instead what I'd like is for the arrays and data within to persist throughout the application, until the engine has been stopped.

My best guess is that it is related to memory allocation and lack of persisting same for arrays, but I'm not sure how I can solve it.

Comment: You can't suppose that the memory layout of Swift structs and C structs is absolutely the same.

Comment: @Sulthan I recognize that, but it works tremendously well as long as I don't have any arrays within the struct (as above question reveals), i.e. C recognizes values and correctly changes them. Based on my research it also seems to be the most recognized way of being able to initialize and use structs in swift. Do you know of a better way to handle structs in Swift? If so I'd love to know.

Comment: If you import the C struct definition directly into Swift (using a bridging header or module map), the layout should remain exactly as it is in C.

Comment: I would suggest writing a few helper functions in C to avoid having a complicated bridge and then just use pointers (and functions) for accessing the data... It might seem like an indirect approach, but I think it's more maintainable and portable.

Comment: C arrays are mapped to Swift as *tuples*.